# gcloud token expires in 60 minutes. Any workaround?

Tags: authentication, gcloud

Is there any possibility to use a API key or something more permanent in terms of gcloud login? I`m using the normal login with my account, but it expires every 60 minutes and I keep having to login in order to be able to use the app.

I`ve tried using an service account, but considering I wanted to retrieve Google Play reviews for an app, I was not able to grant that service account access there(or am I missing something?) and I received 403 error which is expected.

Comment: Are you logging in with `gcloud auth login`? When you do that, a token is generated and saved by gcloud that allows it to create access tokens indefinitely. Access tokens themselves only last 60 minutes, but gcloud should refresh them automatically and transparently. What error are you seeing that you think you need to login again?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to [refresh it](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2#basicsteps) but keep in mind that there is a [limit of the number of refreshes on a token](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2#expiration). This is a work around you could apply